IIS cannot see self-signed certificate added to LocalMachine\Root
I'm trying to configure an ASP.Net application on an IIS server running on Windows 10 Professional so that it runs on SSL (https). I am creating a self-signed certificate using PowerShell (run as Administrator) with the following commands:
$Certificate=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject MyAppName -DnsName MyHostName -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5)

Move-Item (Join-Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My $Certificate.ThumbPrint) -Destination Cert:\LocalMachine\Root

After the above commands I see the certificate in the MMC snap-in under [Certificates - Local Computer\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates].
However, in IIS, in the 'Add Site Binding' dialog it does not show up in SSL Certificate list.

Is there some step that I'm missing?


IIS only reads certificates from local machine's My and WebHosting. 2) Why do you want to use "LocalMachine\Root"? Certificate stores are there for different purposes, and Root is just for root certificates.


@Lex Li I need it to be in Root because this ASP.Net application is being deployed on a local network where other users on the network will access the application from their web browsers (Chrome, Edge etc.). If its not a root certificate, there would be SSL certificate errors when opening the page?

Are you in same domain?

@jdweng Yes, same domain. Its a local office intranet.

Who is the domain administrator? They should teach you thoroughly on certificates and help avoid such misunderstandings. To get rid of HTTPS errors, this domain should have its own CA and your server certificate should come from there (still in My or WebHosting store), while all clients will have the right certificate chains controlled by DC.

There are two things to check first:

Make sure the certificate you added to "Server Certificates" is the
one you created a "Certificate Request" for. If you add a certificate
that wasn’t requested in "Server Certificates", it won’t show up in
IIS binding window even if it does in "Server Certificates" list

Make sure there is a private key in the certificate (steps are below):
Check if the certificate has a private key:

Open mmc. Add Certificates for Computer account

A "key image" should be on the certificate image. You can also check it by double clicking the certificate


If the certificate doesn’t have a private key, run the command below:
certutil -repairstore my [thumbprint]
You should see CertUtil: -repairstore command completed successfully message. Close IIS Manager and open it again. Then check if the certificate appears in the binding window.


More information you can refer to this link: Certificate is missing in IIS binding window.
